# PHP get array elements that contain certain value not key

Tags: php, arrays

I Can't find similar to this is this possible? I have an example array

```
Array
(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [employee_name] => Abegail P.
            [employee_id] => 1297212
            [total_offenses] => 10
            [type] => giveaways
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [employee_name] => Carlota
            [employee_id] => 1855076
            [total_offenses] => 5
            [type] => refund
        )

)
```

I want to retrieve array elements that has only have a giveaway types and display like this.

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [employee_name] => Abegail P.
            [employee_id] => 1297212
            [total_offenses] => 10
            [type] => giveaways
        )
    )
```

Comment: I just wonder if you accept any of those four solution... They did a lot of effort to provide you working results even with the live demo. Go and click on Accept the solution.. https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: All answers have point they all correct for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_filter`

Here is an example:

```
$arr = array
(

    array
        (
            "employee_name" => 'Abegail P.',
            "employee_id" => '1297212',
            "total_offenses" => '10',
            "type" => 'giveaways',
        ),
    array
        (
            "employee_name" => 'Carlota',
            "employee_id" => '1855076',
            "total_offenses" => '5',
            "type" => 'refund',
        )

);


//Use array_filter
$result = array_filter($arr, function($v) {
    //Return if type giveaways
   return $v[ 'type' ] === 'giveaways';
});

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $result );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [employee_name] => Abegail P.
            [employee_id] => 1297212
            [total_offenses] => 10
            [type] => giveaways
        )

)
```

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Answer (score 1):

use [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
$array = array_filter($array, function($value){
    return $value["type"] === "giveaways";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[`array_filter`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) is the perfect  tool for doing that.

```
$key = giveaways; // I assume this is constant value as
                  // its not writtent as literal or variable.
$new_array = array_filter($array, function( $item ) use( $key ) {
    if (item[type'] == $key ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```